# Having clause not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, compare, having

I have following statement

```
select pkid 
from AttendancePosting 
where datename(dw,AttDate) = 'Sunday' and empid=4 and attdate='2015-12-13' 
group by PKId,timeout
--having 9=9
having cast(sum((datepart(minute, timeout)))/2 as float )+''=cast(datepart(minute,timeout) as float) +''
```

The problem is

```
having cast(sum((datepart(minute, timeout)))/2 as float )+''=cast(datepart(minute,timeout) as float) +''
```

Not working. both `cast(sum((datepart(minute, timeout)))/2 as float )` and `cast(datepart(minute,timeout) as float)` bring the same value but still the select statement is not fetching any records, both returns `9`

I have checked it like this

```
select pkid 
from AttendancePosting 
where datename(dw,AttDate) = 'Sunday' and empid=4 and attdate='2015-12-13' 
group by PKId,timeout
having 9=9
```

And its bringing records, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of `+''` in the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: I removed it still not working

Answer (score 1):

First, your statement `datepart(minute, timeout)/2` is going to return an integer.  You can make SQL Server get more precise by being more precise like this `datepart(minute, timeout)/2.`.

Second, floating point numbers are an approximation.  You would do better to use `ROUND()` and specify the number of decimal places you think is appropriate.  For example: `round(sum((datepart(minute, timeout)))/2.0, 3)`.

Comment: I think `group by` returning only one record and so one timeout, so when devide by two the values are not equal

Comment: I think your first step should be to avoid the `float` values because they are not precise and, even though they look like they should be exactly equal, they may not be exactly equal.